# sql multi-table query

Tags: mysql, sql, backend

I have 3 related tables and I would like to show with a query sql a table with the "titulo" of the table "recetas" with the "categoria" of the table "categorias" that is selected, a recipe can have more than one category for that I have created the table "recetas-categorias", I have tried with subqueries but I do not get it, I am a beginner in sql.

```
SELECT r.titulo 
 FROM recetas r 
WHERE r.idreceta=(SELECT rc.idreceta 
                   FROM recetas-categorias 
                  WHERE rc.idcategoria=(SELECT id 
                                         FROM categorias c 
                                        WHERE c.categoria="Internacional"));
```

[relationship of the three tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgAaY.png)

[categorias table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYgRh.png)

[recetas-categorias table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzhCw.png)

[recetas table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPSBv.png)

Attached code of the structure and data

**Recetas table**

```js
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `recetas`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recetas` (
  `idreceta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titulo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `contenido` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `idusuario` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `imagenprincipal` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `valoracion` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idreceta`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

INSERT INTO `recetas` (`idreceta`, `titulo`, `contenido`, `fecha`, `idusuario`, `imagenprincipal`, `valoracion`) VALUES
(1, 'Paella mixta', '<ul class=\"list-group\">\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Cras justo odio</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Morbi leo risus</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Vestibulum at eros</li>\r\n</ul>', '2019-01-15', '1', 'paella.jpg', NULL),
(2, 'Boquerones', '<ul class=\"list-group\">\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Cras justo odio</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Morbi leo risus</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Vestibulum at eros</li>\r\n</ul>', '2019-01-24', '1', 'boquerones.jpg', NULL),
(3, 'Salchichas', '<ul class=\"list-group\">\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Cras justo odio</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Morbi leo risus</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Vestibulum at eros</li>\r\n</ul>', '2019-01-24', '1', 'salchi.jpg', NULL);
COMMIT;
```

**recetas-categorias table**

```js
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `recetas-categorias`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recetas-categorias` (
  `idreceta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idcategoria` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

INSERT INTO `recetas-categorias` (`idreceta`, `idcategoria`) VALUES
(1, 6),
(1, 14),
(3, 9),
(3, 14),
(2, 10);
COMMIT;
```

**categorias table**

```js
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categorias`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

INSERT INTO `categorias` (`id`, `categoria`) VALUES
(1, 'Sopas y cremas'),
(2, 'Salsas'),
(3, 'Potajes'),
(4, 'Ensaladas'),
(5, 'Pastas'),
(6, 'Arroces'),
(7, 'Legumbres'),
(8, 'Huevos'),
(9, 'Carnes'),
(10, 'Pescados'),
(11, 'Mariscos'),
(12, 'Cocteles y refrescos'),
(13, 'Postres y repostería'),
(14, 'Internacional'),
(15, 'Robot de cocina');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Post table structure and example data as text, not as images. Also include expected result from your sample data.

Comment: okey, Thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, from understanding your question, you are perhaps looking to be introduced to MySQL tables joins.

It's a broad category, too broad for an answer in here, so it's probably best to direct you to somewhere like http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/ to learn what they are and how they are used.

In terms of your query, the following amendment:

```
SELECT r.titulo 
 FROM `categorias` c 
INNER JOIN `recetas-categorias` rc ON rc.idcategoria= c.id
INNER JOIN `recetas` r ON r.idreceta = rc.idreceta
WHERE c.categoria="Internacional"
```

returns

```
+-------------+
| paella      |
|-------------|
| salchichas  |
+-------------+
```

...which looks to be what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about "sql joins". Here is how you join those 3 tables:

```
    select r.titulo
    from recetas r
    join recetas-categorias rc
        on rc.idreceta = r.idreceta
    join categorias c
        on c.id = rc.idcategoria
    where c.categoria = 'Internacional'
```

Answer (score 0):

For this operation use [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

```
SELECT r.titulo 
 FROM recetas r 
JOIN recetas-categorias rc
ON r.idreceta = rc.idreceta  
JOIN categorias c
ON rc.idcategoria = c.id
AND c.categoria="Internacional"
```

or

```
SELECT r.titulo 
FROM recetas r,
     recetas-categorias rc,
     categorias c
WHERE r.idreceta = rc.idreceta  
AND rc.idcategoria = c.id
AND c.categoria="Internacional"
```